# jQuery replace "£" with "&pound;" UTF-8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-entities, html-encode

I'm trying to encode HTML special characters in strings from an uploaded file. It's working with everything except the "£" sign and, honestly, I have NO idea why

I'm getting the text from an element using:

```
var outputText = $("#displayAreaHidden").html();

outputText = encodeText(outputText);
```

Then I'm trying to find & replace using a large object of special chars and their HTML code replacements

```
function encodeText(text) {
    var encodeTable = {
        //Huge object here
    };


    $.each(encodeTable, function(key, value) {
        if(text.indexOf(key) > -1) {
            text = text.replace(key, value);
        }
    })

    return text;
}
```

Where in the case of the "£" sign, the object has:

```
"£" : "&pound;"
```

This isn't being picked up so the replacement doesn't happen. I've tried with both `£` and `&pound;` being passed in both the original HTML file and the object itself yet it's still not being picked up.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

### EDIT

Just updating with my current code:

(The HTML is "made" by an uploaded HTML file)

JS

```
function processData() {
    var data = $.parseHTML(fr.result);

    $("#displayAreaHidden").html(data);

    var outputText = $("#displayAreaHidden").html();

    $("#displayArea").text(encodeText(outputText));

}

function encodeText(text) {
  var text = escape(text);
  var encodeTable = {
        "£" : "&pound;"
    };

  $.each(encodeTable, function(key, value) {
      text = text.replace(escape(key), escape(value));
  })

  return unescape(text);
}
```

HTML

```
<textarea id="displayArea"></textarea>

<div id="displayAreaHidden"></div>
```

Comment: There's not much point in doing the `.indexOf()` test first.

Comment: Also you should probably be creating  a regular expression from each key, with the `g` flag, or else the `.replace()` call will only affect the first instance of each key.

Comment: What character set are you using for your pages? Because you don't necessarily need to encode the symbol, if it shows up naturally, as it does in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the replies - @Pointy I see what you mean, will probably remove that. The regex is a great idea, thanks!

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan The charset is UFT-8, but this tool is designed for use on HTML emails so all the special characters ideally need to be encoded before use, hence the tool :)

Comment: You mentioned UTF8 in the question title. If you're really using UTF8, then you shouldn't need to encode a `£` sign as `&pound;` because the browser should display the correct character with you just sending the symbol itself. If you're sending the symbol and not getting the character displayed correctly in the browser, then ideally you need to investigate what's broken in your UTF8 rather than trying to fix it by using HTML entities. See also [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: If your mail goes out with a UTF-8 charset, the same applies - no need to encode.

Comment: The characters do need encoding (View in browser links on emails etc. will not display non-encoded chars correctly), so I do need to do this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML-encoding in JavaScript/jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/html-encoding-in-javascript-jquery)

Comment: All that the HTML entity does is ask the mail reader or browser to show a particular UTF-8 character anyway.

Comment: Unicode standard defines approximately 100,000 characters, so you would need a really huge table to cover the full set. You should try to fix your document encoding instead of creating complex workarounds. Or at least use numeric entities, `String.prototype.codePointAt()` can help with that.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't working? https://jsfiddle.net/6jz1x22y/

Comment: Any reason why this couldn't work? https://jsfiddle.net/q1medwtp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encoding "special" characters is absolutely not the right way to solve this problem. You should correctly specify the document encoding instead.

Anyway, the most probable cause of the problem with the pound sign is that [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) will only replace the first occurrence unless you use the global flag:

```
'XX'.replace('X', 'O'); // => 'OX'
'XX'.replace(/X/g, 'O'); // => 'OO'
```

Also, it would be neither efficient nor reliable to maintain a table for all characters that need to be encoded, such as foreign alphabets, currencies, math symbols, emojis, and fancy punctuation.

Here's a function that will encode characters within the basic multilingual plane (which includes the pound sign, but doesn't include emoji):

```
function encode(string) {
    return string.replace(/./g, function(char) {
        var code = char.charCodeAt(0);
        return code > 127 ? '&#' + code + ';' : char;
    });
}
```

It scans the string one character at a time (instead of making multiple passes), and replaces non-ASCII characters with decimal HTML codes.

It doesn't escape special HTML characters such as `<` and `&`. They should be encoded beforehand if that's what you want. To correctly encode the full Unicode space you would need a more complex function that combines surrogate pairs.

Comment: Thanks for this! Very well explained. I understand that /really/ I shouldn't even be doing this, it was just confusing me so I wanted to know why and solve it - which you've done marvelously!

Answer (score 2):

You can get all text of the html and use this Regular Expression:

```
var outputText = $("body");

outputText = encodeText(outputText);

function encodeText(text) {

      var text = $(text).children().each(function () {
          $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(/£/g,"&pound;") );
      });

    return text;
}
```

Comment: To add to this, you can turn your object key into a regex with `new RegExp(key, 'g')`.  this will result in a `/£/g` object for the key "£".